# How does the C++ Standard defines the function generation of template classes

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I am currently investigating the code generation of templates and I don't know if what I see is compiler or C++ specific. And if it is compiler specific, all compilers do it that way.
If I pass a reference as class template parameter to the class, are only the functions shich use the parameter directly and the functions that call those functions generated in the executable?

```
struct TestConfiguration
{
    uint8_t val1_;
};

template<const TestConfiguration& config>
class TestClass 
{
public:

    uint8_t writeData( uint8_t data ) 
    {
        return writeDataImpl( data, config);
    }
    uint8_t writeDataImpl( uint8_t data, const TestConfiguration& config_param)
    {
        data = data_ + config_param.val1_;
        return data;
    }

    uint8_t getData()
    {
        return data_;
    }

    uint8_t data_;
};
constexpr TestConfiguration config2{0};
TestClass<config2> obj2;
constexpr TestConfiguration config1{0};
TestClass<config1> obj;

int main()
{
    return obj2.writeData(2) + obj.writeData(3);
}
```

I would expect writeDataImpl and writeData to be generated both twice. However what the compiler does is generating writeData twice and writeDataImpl once. Is this common behaviour?

Comment: Read the standard?

Comment: Implementation details are not specified by standard.

Comment: I cannot find it... And I do not even know if its defined or undefined behaviour.

Comment: Seems like a perfectly valid question to me, although I do not know the answer.

Comment: Ok, but what can I expect the compilers to do? Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: I added a main.

Comment: `writeData` depends on the template argument, `writeDataImpl` doesn't.

Comment: The standard does not specify how many instantiations there should be, or whether identical instantiations can be "collapsed" into a single function. Modern compilers are pretty good at not generating unnecessary code.

Comment: I would expect any compiler worth its salt to generate [no code at all](https://godbolt.org/z/q56caW96v) for this program.

Comment: Yes, just without optimization it generates code (in this case all code). However this example is just to show the concept I was thinking off. I tried it out and my compiler does generate writeDataImpl just once in most cases. However there are some weird border cases where it unfortunatly does not...